# react-router-redux history not being accepted (from sample code)

Tags: react-router, react-router-redux

Working with the example in the README at

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-redux

I have created this layout in my index:

```js
// attach the redux dev tools extension for Chrome
const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

// apply router logic as middleware
const history = createHistory();
const router_mw = routerMiddleware(history);


// second arg to createStore is the inital redux store state
const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  initialState,
  composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(
      ReduxPromise,
      ReduxThunk,
      router_mw
    )
));

// --> add routes for logs, opsec, etc. later
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={ store }>
    <ConnectedRouter history={ history }>  // <- error here
      <div>
        <Route exact path="/" component={ LoginScreen } />
        <Route path="/comp1" component={ comp1 } />
        <Route path="/comp2" component={ comp2 } />
      </div>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>
  , document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Any attempt to compile it complains about { history } in the ConnectedRouter entry point:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check your code at index.js:52.
```

What am I missing? This is a `react-router-redux` retrofit - going back to `react-router` (and changing `ConnectedRouter` to `BrowserRouter`) and everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `react-router-dom@4.2.2` and had the same problem until update `react-router-redux` to `^5.0.0-alpha.9`.

If you are using `react-router-dom@4` you should use `react-router-redux@5`, it is said in [react-router-redux repo](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux):

> The next version of react-router-redux will be 5.0.0 and will be compatible with react-router 4.x. It is currently being actively developed [over there](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-redux). Feel free to help out!